# Using iTunes navigation with lists. Is it gone now?

Tags: itunes

I was a big fan and heavy user of the list interface in previous iTunes. For example, it had the columns at the top, Genre, Artist, Album (i think :) ).

I was surprised in iTunes 12 that this feature is not found. This is a fundamental search-feature, where is it?

What am I missing? Is it done?

-Justin

Comment: Check the carat in the top-right corner of the iTunes window when browsing your Music. Switch to Songs view.

Comment: What do you mean? it is still there!

Answer (score 1):

Posted as answer just to provide image…

As douggro says, the caret at top right of the window, when in Music view, gives you the old view back.

*Pro Tip:* if you also want the old view back when editing track info, opt/right click & Get Info.

[image]